# Why is this query not returning any results?

Tags: java, mysql

I am leaning some Java for school, and for some reason the code below doesn't return any results? Is there a problem with this code? There is a single record in the mysql database, with a `studentID` (which is `int(10)`) of 12.

```
public static ResultSet GetByID(int studentID) {
    // This method loads the mysql driver and establishes the database connection
    Connect();

    ResultSet results = null;

    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM student where studentID = ?";

        PreparedStatement statement = Connection.prepareStatement(query);

        statement.setInt(1, studentID);
        results = statement.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LogException(ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    // This method terminates the mysql connection.
    Disconnect();

    return results;
}
```

The calling code is:

```
@Override
public ResultSet query() {
    return DB.GetByID(getStudentID()); // this is 12
}
```

This does not return null, rather just an empty result set.

Comment: Assuming you've made sure that studentID == 10, and that there are no exceptions being thrown?

Comment: are you receiving any error/exception? If not then the student id you are using exists in the databasE?

Comment: I have checked and it returns normally, but when I read the ResultSet returned from this there are no records. It doesn't fall into either of the catch blocks.

Comment: When this method is called with an `int` of 12, it returns nothing, but when I manually run the sql query of `select * from student where studentID = 12` it returns one row.

Comment: Have you tried with a Connection.createStatement() st.executeQuery("select * from student where studentID = 12");

Comment: @Kal that seems to return the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ResultSet` can only be used while the connection is still open.  Read it before you "disconnect".

If fixing that doesn't give you a different result, the most likely cause is that the query didn't match any rows in the table.

---

You should get into the habit of closing connections, streams, etc in `finally` blocks to prevent resource leakage.  (Your lecturer **should have** explained that.  Check your notes / text book.)

---

Finally, since you are a beginner, it is worth pointing out that you should always conform to the accepted Java conventions for method naming.  Java method names should start with a lower-case letter.  `GetByID` should be `getByID` and `Disconnect` should be `disconnect`.

(And if your lecturer / tutor doesn't or didn't dock marks for that, he / she should be condemned to writing Visual Basic for the next 5 years for crimes against the Software Engineering industry.)

Comment: Haha, thanks Stephen C. I work in a .NET environment, old habits die hard. Your stuff worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the resultSet **after** closing the connection you have to use CachedRowSet.
As StephenC said, your ResultSet is empty after closing the connection.